# How to 'Calculate response time & average first response time on the basis of type with date filters' in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables named **contacts** & **messages**. Each contact has two types of messages **incoming and outgoing**. What I want to do is calculate the average time difference between the first incoming & after that the first outgoing message for every contact in contacts table ignoring any incoming message after first incoming message also calculate it by following filters Today: From 00:00 of that day until the data was requested.
Yesterday: From 00:00 until 23:59 the day before data was requested.
Last 14 days: Last 14 days (excluding the day it was requested.)
Last 30 days: Last 30 days (excluding the day it was requested) Below is the DB structure of my table.

**Contact Table:**

```
|id    |name      |created_at         |
--------------------------------------
|   1  | Alex     |2019-01-31 00:27:9 |
|   2  | Ammy     |2016-01-31 04:12:9 |
```

**Message Table:**

```
|id    |type     |contactId  |created_at         |
--------------------------------------------------
|   1  |  incoming    |  1   |2019-01-31 00:27:16|
|   2  |  incoming    |  1   |2019-01-31 00:27:20|
|   3  |  outgoing    |  1   |2019-01-31 02:37:16|
|   4  |  outgoing    |  1   |2019-01-31 02:37:25|
|   5  |  incoming    |  1   |2019-01-31 03:47:04|
|   6  |  outgoing    |  1   |2019-01-31 03:50:04|
|   7  |  incoming    |  2   |2016-01-31 04:12:16|
|   8  |  outgoing    |  2   |2016-01-31 04:13:16|
```

***Expected Result***

```
|contactId |averageTime(min) |
-------------------------
|   1      | 66.5             |
|   2      | 1               |
```

Comment: The average time for contactid 1 appears to be (130mins + 3 mins) / 2 = 66.5mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your result set is wrong...

```
SELECT contactid
     , SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(diff)) averagetime
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.contactid
            , MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(b.created_at))-TIME_TO_SEC(a.created_at) diff
         FROM 
            ( SELECT i
                   , contactid
                   , type
                   , MIN(created_at) created_at 
                FROM 
                   ( SELECT contactid
                          , type
                          , created_at
                          , CASE WHEN @prev = type THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
                          , @prev:=type 
                       FROM message
                          , (SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
                      ORDER 
                         BY contactid,id
                   ) x 
               GROUP 
                  BY i
                   , contactid
                   , type
            ) a
         JOIN message b
           ON b.contactid = a.contactid 
          AND b.created_at >= a.created_at
        WHERE a.type = 'incoming'
          AND b.type = 'outgoing'
        GROUP
           BY a.contactid
            , a.created_at
      ) n
  GROUP
     BY contactid;
```